# Can I use different apple Id (two) in a (one) Xcode to develop (two) different react-native project

Tags: swift, xcode, react-native-ios, provisioning-profile, apple-developer-account

I have two different react-native project with two different apple Id. Can I able to use the same Xcode to develop two different app different profile.

My Clarifications:

1. Is it make any issues with the signing
2. If I use two different accounts in Xcode does it make any issues or send any notifications to any one of the account holder
3. What is the best practise to build two different app with two different profiles in one Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

Can I able to use the same Xcode to develop two different app different profile ?

Yes you can use different profiles for different apps in same xcode. you need to select correct team

[image]

[image]